# Problem with ROS Networking

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have already tried this tutorial,

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup

and everything was perfect, so I don't have a problem with Turtlebot networking setup.
Now I'm trying to follow this tutorial

http://nootrix.com/2012/06/ros-networking/

On my workstation, first I run

```
ssh name@turtlebot_lap
```

and when I run

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

I get this error

```
turtlesim_node: cannot connect to X server
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55421/problem-with-ros-networking./) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that tutorial is not very clear. The turtlesim_node has to be run on the actual machine itself (ie in that tutorial, you have to run it on the r2d2 machine) and not through ssh. This is because turtlesim_node requires gui (X server) and you have to use "ssh -X name@turtlebot_lap" in order to see gui through ssh.

If you want to follow that tutorial, I would suggest using the r2d2 machine, open a terminal to ssh into c3po, and run roscore. Then, open a new terminal (this will be the r2d2 terminal) and run turtlesim_node.

Following the tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) would be easier.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-01**:
@TheSkyfall please mark your question as answered, if this solution solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also have two other options.

I wanted to roslaunch a gui so after hours of searching I found a way!

If you want to run the node and gui on the remote machine, after establishing ssh connection run this command.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or (if the first one didn't work)

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

the turtlesim node will be launched on the remote machine.

but if you want to get the gui on your main computer just use:

```
ssh -X
```

The good thing is by editing my env.sh file I was able to roslaunch my nodes. I just add the first command at the end of my env.sh file.

---

Originally posted by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) with karma: 146 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3